# Couchdb query with AND operator

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to simulate this query with couchdb views?

```
select * from table where key1 = 'value 1' AND key2 = 'value 2';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Your map function will look like this:

```
function(doc){
  if ( doc.key1 && doc.key2 ){
    emit([doc.key1, doc.key2], null);
  }
}
```

And then you would query it like this:

```
.../myview?startkey=["value 1","value 2"]&endkey=["value 1","value 2"]
```